# t:selectOneRadio with t:radio renders as nothing

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tomahawk

I added radio button tags to the following JSP (abridged and anonymized) in a JSF application. It does not render any radio buttons, nor does it call any of the relevant methods in the managed bean.

```
<h:form id="orderForm">

<t:selectOneRadio
    id="theRadioInput"
    layout="spread"
    forceId="true"
    forceIdIndex="false"
    value="#{bean.aStringProperty}"
    styleClass="field">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.radioSelectItems}"/>
    <a4j:support 
        event="onclick" 
        reRender="theRadioInput"
        actionListener="#{bean.listener}"/>  
</t:selectOneRadio>
<rich:dataTable 
    id="dataTable" 
    value="#{bean.listOfDataObjects}" 
    var="curDataObject" 
    rowKeyVar="index">
    <rich:column style="border-left">
        <rich:panel style="border:none">
        ...
        </rich:panel>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{curDataObject.location}" styleClass="label" style="font-size:12;"/>                                                                                  
        <rich:dataList  var="item" value="#{curDataObject.someItems}" rowKeyVar="itemIndex" styleClass="noWrap">
            <h:outputText value="Some data:" styleClass="label" />
            <h:outputText value="#{item}" styleClass="label" />
        </rich:dataList>
        <t:radio for=":orderForm:theRadioInput" index="#{index}" rendered="curDataObject.radioApplicable"/>
    </rich:column>                                  
</rich:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

I wonder, does the fact that I'm using `<rich:dataTable>`, not `<t:dataTable>`make a difference? What else could prevent the radio buttons from appearing at all? Not even `bean.getRadioSelectItems()` gets called during rendering. (It does get called later, when the page is submitted.)

If you insist, maybe I'll post the relevant code from the managed bean, but I don't think that's the issue, since it's not even getting called.

The "real" version of this page works and has been in a production application for several years. The addition of radio buttons is the only change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps to mind here is that the `rendered` attribute of the radio button is attempting to evaluate a string. It looks like you intended it to be an EL expression, but left out the braces.

Comment: The first thing was the right thing. Thanks for lending your sharp eyes!